# Can we bump threads?

Tags: support

I have seen a post [here](https://superuser.com/q/467599/345828), which I was reluctant to flag, but apparently has just been deleted.

The post was an answer to "up" the thread. Obviously, that is *not an answer*, and thus deserved a flag, but I wanted to ask this without flagging (since I'm probably annoying the mods by making questions in the flags).

Is it ever desirable, or accepted, to update a thread to make it active again? If so, is there any standard procedure to do it?

Comment: Don't ever update a question or answer just with the intention of "bumping" it (that is the correct terminology; "up" is too vague and could also refer to upvoting, which is different). If you want a question to get more attention, put a rep bounty on it.

Comment: I am aware of that, and I wasn't the one making the bump, but seeing it made me think about it. Also, I'll edit this thread's title accordingly, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any post that simply says "Me too", "Bump", "Up" or any variation thereof is Considered Harmful and should be flagged so that it can be dealt with using extreme prejudice.  It is not "good form" nor is it useful.

If you can add information to the question, then an edit will earn it a bump but you should only do this if you *really* have something to contribute.

Alternatively setting a bounty will earn it a revisit to the front page as well as get it onto the [featured](https://superuser.com/questions?sort=featured) page where one of our resident bounty hunters may kill it good and proper.

Comment: I'll ask the same I asked Journeyman Geek: What if I find a question in Google, that has no answers? Maybe it's not worth to bounty it; I shouldn't edit the OP's question for my own needs, and asking it again is creating a duplicate thread. Bounties are the only solution?

Comment: If you can provide more information than the original question, are actively going to respond to people asking you about it, and you can point to the original which has obviously been abandoned then I, for one, am fine with a duplicate.  Point out in your question that you saw the abandoned question but you can provide X, Y and Z extra information that sets it apart.  Be forthcoming and open and say that while it *is* a duplicate you can put more work into making it its own question.  If you can provide absolutely nothing of extra value, then yes, bounty it.

Comment: If you get a good answer then we could potentially close the duplicate as a duplicate of *your* question rather than the other way around.

Comment: Makes sense, and seems like a reasonable approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yeah.If you want people to pay attention to it, bounty it.

If its your own question *substancial* edits with more information would be an acceptable way too. Flagging non answers is entirely fine.

Comment: What if I find a question in Google, that has no answers? Maybe it's not worth to bounty it; I shouldn't edit the OP's question for my own needs, and asking it again is creating a duplicate thread. Bounties are the only solution?